# Download iCloud file from shared link using bash

Tags: bash, macos, url, download

I want to download a file from iCloud. I can share a link to a file. However the file is not directly linked in the urls, but the "real" download url can be retrieved:

```
#!/bin/bash
# given "https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/<ID>#<Filename>
ID="...."
URL=$(curl 'https://ckdatabasews.icloud.com/database/1/com.apple.cloudkit/production/public/records/resolve' \
  --data-raw '{"shortGUIDs":[{"value":"$ID"}]}' --compressed \
  jq -r '.results[0].rootRecord.fields.fileContent.value.downloadURL')
curl "$URL" -o myfile.ext
```

Sorce: https://gist.github.com/jpillora/702ded79330043e38e8202b5c73835e5

```
        "fileContent" : {
          "value" : {
...
            "downloadURL" : "https://cvws.icloud-content.com/B/CYo..."
          },
```

This is, however not working:

```
rl: (6) Could not resolve host: jq
curl: (3) nested brace in URL position 17:
{
  "results" : [ {
    "shortGUID" : {
      "value" : "$ID",
      "shouldFetchRootRecord" : true
    },
    "reason" : "shortGUID cannot be null or empty",
    "serverErrorCode" : "BAD_REQUEST"
  } ]
}
```

Any ideas, what I can do to make this work?

Comment: First, did you fill in `ID="..."` with your file's ID? Second, I think the backslash after `--compressed` should be a `|` (pipe). Maybe a typo in the gist. As such it's passing `jq` as an argument to curl, which is wrong. Hence `Could not resolve host: jq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by installing jq and adding the ID directly instead of using `$id`. Just installing jq was not sufficient.

```
brew install jq


#!/bin/bash
# given "https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/<ID>#<Filename>

URL=$(curl 'https://ckdatabasews.icloud.com/database/1/com.apple.cloudkit/production/public/records/resolve' \
  --data-raw '{"shortGUIDs":[{"value":"ID"}]}' --compressed | jq -r '.results[0].rootRecord.fields.fileContent.value.downloadURL')
Echo $url
curl "$URL" -o myfile.ext
```

Answer (score 0):

as @dan mentioned, `jq` is not a curl argument, its a separate command. hence you would need to `|` pipe it instead of `\`.

So the command would look something like this:

`URL=$(curl 'https://ckdatabasews.icloud.com/database/1/com.apple.cloudkit/production/public/records/resolve' \ --data-raw '{"shortGUIDs":[{"value":"$ID"}]}' --compressed | jq -r '.results[0].rootRecord.fields.fileContent.value.downloadURL')`

Comment: Sounds promising, but I still get this error:

    curl: (23) Failed writing body
    curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
    curl: (3) nested brace in URL position 15:
    {"shortGUIDs":[{"value":"$ID"}]}
                  ^

Comment: hmm... thats odd. 
1. could you tell me what youre trying to do with  `--data-raw`? according to [curl man page](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-raw), it seems like its used for POST methods.
2. the last line `curl "$URL" -o myfile.ext` would need to be fixed as well since `curl` is already been called in `$URL` and `-o myfile.ext` would be used as arguments for the `jq` command

Comment: As far as I understand it fetches the "real" download url first with curl. Then it downloads from this url. I removed --data-raw but still the same. I don't know if it is required. What do you suggest?

Comment: can you try replace the URL variable with ```URL=$(curl 'https://ckdatabasews.icloud.com/database/1/com.apple.cloudkit/production/public/records/resolve' --data-raw '{"shortGUIDs":[{"value":"$ID"}]}' --compressed |  jq -r '.results[0].rootRecord.fields.fileContent.value.downloadURL')```. When i did, I got the message ```curl: (6) Could not resolve host: null``` since I dont have the ```ID``` I am recieving an incorrect json response. Please fill in the right ```ID``` and try run it with the above line.

Comment: curl: (23) Failed writing body
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL